# The convergence of $p$-laplace equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, bounded-variation

Let $g\in L^\infty(\Omega)$ be given, where $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^2$ is open bounded with smooth boundary.

Define, for $1<p\leq 2$,
$$
u_p:=\operatorname{argmin}\left\{\int_\Omega|u-g|^pdx+\int_\Omega|\nabla u|^pdx,\,\,u\in W^{1,p}(\Omega)\right\}
$$
and 
$$
u_1:=\operatorname{argmin}\left\{\int_\Omega|u-g|dx+|Du|(\Omega),\,\,u\in BV(\Omega)\right\}
$$
where by $|Du|(\Omega)$ we denote the total variation of $u$ as a $BV$ function.

My question: could we expect, as $p\to 1$,
$$
u_p\to u_1
$$
strongly in $L^1$?

Moreover, could we expect, as $p\to 1$,
$$
\|\nabla u_p\|_{L^p}\to |Du_1|(\Omega)
$$
too?